# Salt Stack boto.vpc Failed to create subnet conflicts with another subnet

Tags: salt-stack, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to verify the contents of an amazon VPC using boto.vpc. But instead of verifying the contents of the subnet, it's trying to create it. I gave the details of the existing subnet in the init.sls file:

```
Ensure VPC exists:
    boto_vpc.present:
        - name: dlab
        - cidr_block: 10.xx.xx.0/24
        - dns_hostnames: True
        - region: us-east-1
        - keyid: keyid
        - key: key

Ensure subnet exists:
    boto_vpc.subnet_present:
        - name: dlab
        - vpc_id: vpc-xxxxxxx
        - cidr_block: 10.xx.xx.0/24
        - region: us-east-1
        - keyid: keyid
        - key: key
```

And when I run the command, this is the result I get:

```
[root@salt get_vpc]# salt '*' state.apply
salt.localdomain:
----------
          ID: Ensure VPC exists
    Function: boto_vpc.present
        Name: dlab
      Result: True
     Comment: VPC present.
     Started: 14:36:19.166569
    Duration: 312.981 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: Ensure subnet exists
    Function: boto_vpc.subnet_present
        Name: dlab
      Result: False
     Comment: Failed to create subnet: Bad Request: The CIDR '10.60.58.0/24' conflicts with another subnet
     Started: 14:36:19.479896
    Duration: 355.565 ms
     Changes:

Summary for salt.localdomain
------------
Succeeded: 1
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     2
Total run time: 668.546 ms
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

The VPC is verified. But salt is trying to create a new subnet, instead of telling me about the one that's already there. The name of the subnet specified in the top file under Ensure subnet exists is right!

Why is this happening? How can I get salt to verify the subnet instead of trying to create it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution, I have not tested it but if you have the `subnet_id` then you might be able to use it

```
Ensure subnet exists:
    module.run:
        - name: boto_vpc.subnet_exists
        - subnet_id: subnet-foo-id
```

This module will Check if a subnet exists. Returns True if the subnet exists, otherwise returns False. according to the [docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.boto_vpc.html#salt.modules.boto_vpc.subnet_exists)